# Project root folder image in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Im using a thymeleaf template to generate a PDF file, im trying to add a image to the HTML that is located in the root folder of the project, but the image is not rendering, is there a way to doing this?

The image is created in the program, so i cant just add it in resources folder.
Folder structure:
template is in src/main/resources/templates
image that im trying to add is in the root of the project

[image]

Comment: can you add the directory of your project?

Comment: no. I tried getting a empty template with just the img tag, and it worked adding just the src="GraficoUmidade.png", but when i try with the final template it doesnt render the image.

Comment: You mentioned that `<img src="GraficoUmidade.png">` works OK. Therefore this should also work: `<img th:src="${filename}">` - assuming your template is set up to use Thymeleaf, and assuming your Thymeleaf `filename` variable contains the actual file name "GraficoUmidade.png".

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide a [mre]? Also, I assume DonatoAmassa was asking for the _directory structure_ so we can see where you are storing your image file and your Thymeleaf template, etc...

Comment: i edited and added a print of the file structure, i tried doing what andrewjames said but it didnt work.

Comment: Suggestion: Your image file can be placed somewhere where it can be served as a URL resource. Typically that would be in your web app's `static` folder, or in a publicly accessible location in your web app container, or in some other static content server. In other words, if you can display your image file using a URL in the address bar of a browser, then you can handle it in Thymeleaf, in the equivalent way.